# Adding Cloudfront to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a shop system that uses wordpress EDD plugin to sell digital files.
(big files around 3 gig on average)

Files are uploaded to an S3 bucket.

To get everybody the best possible download speed i am thinking of adding a cloudfront distribution distribution to my bucket.

Now my question is:

1. does using cloudfront distribution on the bucket make sense if my goal is to get worldwide customers the best possible download speed?
2. Would the S3 links that i enter in my shop system (the shop system is creating temp links for customers based on them) remain the same, and all the clever distribution happens "behind the scenes"?

Or would those S3 links break when adding cloudfront distribution?

Sorry if this is a stupid question but i am no expert on this...

Thanks!
D.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. does using cloudfront on the bucket make sense if my goal is to get worldwide customers the best possible download speed?

Yes cloud front is best product for your case study for getting a better download speed for worldwide customers.

> 2.Would the S3 links that i enter in my shop system (the shop system is creating temp links for customers based on them) remain the same, and all the clever distribution happens "behind the scenes"?

No the S3 links will not remain same they will change to the cloud front links. So for example if you upload a image to "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/image.jpg" it will change to something like this "https://d112354awyquir.cloudfront.net/bucketname/image.jpg"

Comment: Thanks - that helps a lot!  But i just created a testbucket and added cloudfront distribution to it. in my s3 bucket the links remain the same - where can i see the cloudfront links you mentioned (as those are the ones i need to enter for the products in my shop i guess)

Comment: For that Link to work you have to point your application domains towards the Cloudfront and then check the image upload functionality